# List array in 3 variables

Tags: php

I am noob in php and i need help for list this array in 3 variables.

```
Array ( [ram] => 2,3, [almacenamiento] => 16,32, [marca] => Huawey,Samsung, )
```

I want this :

```
$ram= "2,3,";

$almacenamiento="16,32,";

$marca="Huawey,Samsung,";
```

I only know list array simple with `foreach()`

```
print_r($_POST);

$result=$_POST;

foreach($result as $indice=>$valor){

    print"$indice";//INDICE
    print"$valor";//VALOR
}
```

Comment: `<?php extract($array); ?>` [be careful can be dangerous](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a keyed array you're using

```
$ram = $array['ram'];
```

If it is a $_POST variable (form submit, could also be a $_GET)

```
$ram = $_POST['ram'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use extract to pull out the variables from the array.

```
$arr = Array ( "ram" => "2,3" , "almacenamiento" => "16,32" , "marca" => "Huawey,Samsung");
Extract ($arr);

Echo $ram; // "2,3"
```

https://3v4l.org/0qv6I

However I usually recommend keeping the values in the array and not extracting them.
Only in rare cases is there a point of extracting the variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `extract()` method, it will convert the array keys into values:

```
$arr = array ( "ram" => "2,3" , "almacenamiento" => "16,32" , "marca" => "Huawey,Samsung");

extract($arr);

echo $ram; //2,3
echo $almacenamiento; //16,32
echo $marca; //Huawey,Samsung
```

Here you can find more details about `extract()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that uses array [destructuring](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php) (see [here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/short_list_syntax), too) and it works in PHP 7.1.10+:

```
<?php

[$ram,$almacenamiento, $marca ]= array_values(["ram" => "2,3", 
                                               "almacenamiento" => "16,32", 
                                               "marca" => "Huawey,Samsung"
                                               ]);
var_dump($ram,$almacenamiento, $marca);
```

see [live code](https://3v4l.org/j3A4i#output)

One of the disadvantages of using array destructuring is that if one is not careful, one could overwrite a variable's value.  The same may occur if you use extract(), unless you provide it the paramter EXTR_SKIP, as the following example illustrates:

```
<?php

$a = ["red"=>"rouge","blue"=>"sea","rally"=>"game","trolley"=>"SF"];


$red = "heifer";

extract($a, EXTR_SKIP);

echo "$red, $blue, $rally, $trolley\n";
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/kNrHb)

However, in *Programming PHP* by Rasmus Lerdorf et al (1st edition), one is advised to avoid potential variable conflict by using a parameter EXTR_PREFIX_SAME which affixes a user-specified prefix to extracted variables.

Lastly, you may automate generating multiple variables based on the array's values, using the list construct along with array_values(), as follows:

```
<?php

list($ram,$almacenamiento, $marca )= array_values(["ram" => "2,3", 
                                               "almacenamiento" => "16,32", 
                                               "marca" => "Huawey,Samsung"
                                               ]);
var_dump($ram,$almacenamiento,$marca);
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/nBGi2#output)

With list(), one may also overwrite variables.  So one should exercise care and test whether any variables already exist before using them with list(); see example [here](https://3v4l.org/8XkVH#output).

Comment: Your method will also overwrite the variables just like extract. https://3v4l.org/NgKbK . There is no difference in that, the only difference is that your method **must** follow the array items. Example https://3v4l.org/AbggS switching places on array items or list variables means your output is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use $$ to create variables with the same name as the keys of the array, like this:

```
foreach($values as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;
}
```